# Trying to change Flex 3 ToggleButtonBar dataprovider on user or admin log in

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to change Flex 3 ToggleButtonBar dataprovider on user or admin log in. I'm trying to use 2 viewstack, and I've got a component where the login form is in the component. What should I do to define the dataprovider based on user log in?

Answer (score 0):

Try manually assigning to the dataProvider property instead of using binding.  I know this works with string arrays and other data providers, and I suspect it will work with view stacks.  You need an initialization function that runs during login that can distinguish between user or admin, and then manually assign the data provider in that function.